# Div with scroll over another div with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two containers (c1 and c2) with a long list inside of it, one over the other, both with scroll.

I need to be able to keep the c1 scroll position when the c2 opens and c2 has to open in the top of the container.

When I close c2, I need to go back to the same position where I was at c1.

The problem is that c1 is long and remains visible under c2 and I am not able to go from c1 to c2 and come back to c1 to the same scroll position.

I have build a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="btn1">Show Over DIV</div>
<div id="btn2">Hide Over DIV</div>
<div id="div-under">
  <ul>
    <li>DIV Under</li>
    <li>DIV Under</li>
    <li>DIV Under</li>
  </ul></div>
<div id="div-over">
  <ul>
    <li>DIV Over</li>
    <li>DIV Over</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$("#btn1").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeIn();
    $("#btn1").fadeOut();
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeOut();
    $("#btn1").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeOut();
});
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 15;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#btn2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 25;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#div-under {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: green;
}

#div-over {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jx9dryz7/

Comment: What you asking for is not clear. Please edit your post with proper explanation.

Comment: Have you tried #div-under and #div-over with position: fixed

Comment: @divy3993 Hi, which part? I have included a working example to be explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check once by adding only one more css property to both of your container DIVs

```
overflow: auto;
```

The CSS should be like follows

```
#div-under {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
background-color: green;
overflow: auto;
}

#div-over {
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
z-index: 20;
background-color: red;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```js
$("#btn1").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeIn();
    $("#btn1").fadeOut();
  $("#div-under").scrollTop(0);
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeOut();
    $("#btn1").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeOut();
  $("#div-over").scrollTop(0);
});
```

```css
#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#btn1 {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 200px;
    z-index: 15;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#btn2 {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: 25;
    background-color: yellow;
}

#div-under {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: auto;
}

#div-over {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 20;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="btn1">Show Over DIV</div>
<div id="btn2">Hide Over DIV</div>
<div id="div-under">
    <ul>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
        <li>DIV Under</li>
    </ul></div>
<div id="div-over">
        <ul>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
        <li>DIV Over</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! What a simple solution, at the first tests I made it seems to work fine, how the auto changes almost everything? In the mobile (iPhone) I have lost the "fluid" scrolling with this, do you know why?

Comment: to make the scrolling work properly on iPhone you can try using `overflow-y: scroll; /* has to be scroll, not auto */
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Comment: Great! BTW do you know a way to scroll to the top of the over div when you go back (and where in the first time you open it you have scroll down) ?

Comment: Please check the revised code snippet `$("#btn1").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeIn();
    $("#btn1").fadeOut();
  $("#div-under").scrollTop(0);
});

$("#btn2").on("click", function () {

    $("#div-over").fadeOut();
    $("#btn1").fadeIn();
    $("#btn2").fadeOut();
  $("#div-over").scrollTop(0);
});`

Comment: Thanks but I have an issue with this solution that I have also tried, is that you can see the div going up will you are hiding it... :(